# How to know which ibeacon is ranging to input some info for it in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

My app will ranging the specified UUID beacon then display them on the tableview. When user select any beacon, the app will push the 1 viewcontroller for user to input the information for that beacon (ex: name, detail..) to store in the database. My problem is how to know which selected ibeacon because the proximity UUID, Major and Minor are the same. Can I get the unique device UUID when ranging? Please give me some advice to do that? Thanks so much.

Comment: In order to identify the beacon, you can set different Major & Minor values for different beacons.

Comment: Did you solve your problem. If you find my answer help you out then can you accept and upvote please

Answer (score 2):

The combination of UUID, Major and Minor should be unique - or at least unique to a location if you want multiple beacons with the same configuration to cover a bigger area.

Two beacons with all three values the same are indistinguishable - at least as far as the iBeacon standard goes.  Vendors may add additional BLE capabilities to their beacons which can be used via a Core Bluetooth connection, but not via Core Location beacon discovery.

Answer (score 1):

UUID are same for all becon but Major and Minor value are different so Major and Minor value determine about particular beacon . Be sure about your  Major and Minor value of particular beacons

Answer (score 0):

A region is defined by either UUID, UUID + Major, or UUID + Major + Minor. It is not mandatory to define your regions by Major and Minor, but it's useful if you're using multiple Beacons. It would probably be best to explain it on an example. Imagine that you're owner of a chain of supermarkets. You want to install Beacons in your venues, so every Beacon has the same UUID - UUID of your chain. Every shop in your chain has its dedicated Major value. And in every shop, each section has its dedicated Minor value. This way you can display notifications based on region constisting of all the values, so they're very specific to where your customer currently is - whether he's browsing books in Antwerp or gardening tools in Brussels.

But if you're just running a single, small coffe shop, and use just a single Beacon for the whole venue, your region can be defined by UUID only, because you don't need anything more :)

I hope this will help you.